# Add constraint on geometry column in postgres table, the_geom in a country

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, constraints, postgis

I am creating and manipulating a lot of table with geometry, and sometimes some geometries aren't were there are suppose to be. So, I would like to had a constraint, when I create my tables, to be sure they are in the right polygon (France in my case). I taught to use

```
CHECK (the_geom IS NOT NULL AND ST_Covers(france.the_geom,the_geom) = True)
```

But I don't know how to give the france's geometry, in my create table statement. I suppose that I will have to write the raw geometry every time...

Comment: Yes; the only way to have this in a `CHECK` constraint is to specify a literal. Perhaps you can use a simplified geometry and accept some false negatives.

Comment: Thanks, Laurenz Albe. I'll do that

Comment: What about a `ON BEFORE INSERT`  trigger? You can put a function into the trigger which can do a select for the geometry.